# React input field "required" does not work

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, input

I am using materializecss for my input styling. I added required in my input field. But still I can submit the form without writing anything. Does React change "required" option because my other projects "required" it worked fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { createLogEntry } from "./Api";
import Show from "./Show";
export default function Form() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState("");
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    name: " ",
    description: " "
  });

  const changeHandler = e => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await createLogEntry({
        name: state.name,
        description: state.description
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
    setState({ name: " ", description: " " });
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="app">
        <div className="row">
          <form className="col s12" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {error ? <p className="error">{error}</p> : null}
            <div className="row">
              <div className="input-field col s3">
                <input
                  id="name"
                  type="text"
                  data-length="4"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                  value={state.name}
                  required //This is where I mentioned mandatory
                />
                <label htmlFor="input_text">Topic</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="input-field col s8">
                <textarea
                  id="description"
                  className="materialize-textarea"
                  data-length="120"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                  value={state.description}
                  required //This is where I mentioned mandatory
                ></textarea>
                <label htmlFor="textarea2">Description</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button
              className="btn waves-effect blue lighten-1"
              type="submit"
              name="action"
              disabled={loading}
            >
              {loading ? "Loading..." : "Create Entry"}
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Show />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Ignore this message. I can't upload this post on Stack overflow because it said I have more code than detail information :).

Comment: Can you try ```required="required"``` ??

Comment: Did not work :(.

Comment: Try removing preventDefault

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the question editor interface tells you that you don't have enough text you should listen to that advice. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It will help to keep you questions from ending up in the review queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default state for form field values should be an empty string, while you are setting a space instead:

```js
 const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    name: " ", // There is an extra space here
    description: " " // And here
  });
```

Simply remove the space, and default form validation should work.